# source address of packets in a wifi network is the router and not the pc

Tags: wireless-networking, lan, ping

I executed ping fron machine A (wireless PC) to machine B (wired PC to the wireless router). When I check the packets in machine B with wireshark they have the source address of the router (192.168.1.1). I would expect the source address to be the one of the machine A (192.168.1.10) the one pinging. What is the correct behavior?

Comment: The packets are being sent by the router this is the corect behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The source address of the packet would be the address of the last interface the packet has left to get to the destination, which in this case, would be your router.

Comment: I would have expected the MAC to change but not the source IP. The IP doesn't change when I ping from work to home.

Comment: @Mario Normally the wireless router uses NAT, so it can handle multiple connections (usually about 250).

Comment: @Mario The source MAC address will stay the same throughout the journey.

Answer (score 0):

I rebooted the router (d-link with DDWRT) now it works ok. The IP source address is the one of the machine (interface) that is the source of the packet, not the one of the router.